# openweathermap api return wrong information

Tags: javascript, openweathermap

I am making a weather app using api from openweathermap. It worked but It showed the wrong information about my place and the temperature. Here the code:

```
<h1>weather forcast</h1>
<button id="btn">view</button>
<h2 id="place"></h2>
<h3 id="description"></h3>
<p id="temp"></p>
```

and the script:

```
var getWeather = function(data) {
$.getJSON('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather', {
    lat: data.loc.split(",")[0],
    lon: data.loc.split(",")[1],
    appid: "0596efa13d750207ba4eff57342a81dd" // change this
}, showWeather, 'jsonp');
};

var showWeather = function(data) {
$("#test").text("I AM CHANGED. THANKS!")
$("#temp").text(data.main.temp)
$("#description").text(data.weather[0].description)
$("#place").text(data.name)
};

$(document).ready(function() {
$("#btn").click(function() {
    $.getJSON('http://ipinfo.io/json', getWeather, 'jsonp')
})
})
```

Some people told me the api may return the info about the nearest place where the exchange/isp is but I know the result is wrong because it is a completely strange name. And the temperature, as I tried, it showed `287.944`, it is not the right Fahrenheit or Celcius according to my location's info. In  fact, the temp now in my location is `60 F` or `15 C`

Answer (score 1):

The temperature is in Kelvin because you didn't provide any parameter like units=imperial or units=metric.
The name is of the nearest station where the weather params are coming from.

Enrico